# login page using RESTFULL web service in grails 2.4.4

Tags: web-services, rest, grails, groovy

I am new to restfull webservices, now i wanna create 2 pages first is username page and password pages, when user open the application thats redirects to the username page, user will enter the user name from here i need rest services once username validate from db then that should redirect to password page how can i call this one, i have done with grails but unable to do using rest api, am using jaxrs plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rolling your own, perhaps you can try an existing OAuth 2.0 (web app standard) plugin like the [Grails OAuth 2 Provider Plugin](http://bluesliverx.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/v3/manual/guide/index.html).